# Netezza Query to the database fails with netezza.max.stmt

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, netezza

I am making a Query to two different databases and there are two different dataSources and the pool is created using c3p0. The queries to the second database fails with the following error 
**netezza.max.stmt.handles**

Could You Please help me with this. I have researched and found out that the Driver can process only one query at a time. Is it that the connection is not getting returned to the database or is there any other problem. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be some limit set on user / group / system level. Can you
check if there is any limit set?

```
\du USERNAME -- To check user settings
\dg GROUPNAME - To check group setting
show system default rowsetlimit -- To check system setting
```